# django complicated agregate in three tables

Tags: sql, django, orm

I have a three tables with one main (Transaction) and two dependant(TransactionDialogMessages, TransactionDialogLastAccess).

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 3, default = 'NEW')
    user1 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user1', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    user2 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user2', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    some_info = models.DateTextField()

class TransactionDialogMessages(models.Model):
    transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    message = models.TextField()
    create_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

class TransactionDialogLastAccess(models.Model):
     transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction)
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
     access_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to create one query with complex agregation on this three tables, and result in hash (or queryset) with such structure:

```
{'transaction_id', 'status', 'user1', 'user2', 'some_info', 'count_of_new_messages'}
```

where count_of_new_messages is agregation field, which computed as

```
count (TransactionDialogMessages(transaction = transaction_id, user = request.user, create_datetime > TransactionDialogLastAccess(transaction = transaction_id, user = request.user).access_time))
```

Is it real?

**Updated:**

I created SQL query, which serves my purpose:
`SELECT a.id, a.status, ... , b.COUNT_OF_NEW_MESSAGES FROM transaction a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT b.transaction_id, COUNT(b.transaction_id) AS COUNT_OF_NEW_MESSAGES 
        FROM transactiondialogmessages b 
        LEFT JOIN transactiondialoglastaccess c
        ON b.transaction_id = c.transaction_id
        WHERE b.create_datetime > c.access_time OR c.access_time IS NULL
        GROUP BY b.transaction_id ) b
ON a.id = b.transaction_id;`

But how it's realize on django orm (without raw)?